# About the equilibrium of a flowing reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

Imagine to have a tube (to make a reactor simple) inside which a chemical reactions take place and reactants are constantly fed so overall can be considered in steady-state conditions.

Just to pick one, I assume the reaction to be exothermic.

Now in my mind there are the following two options, one of them is not clear.

1. Assuming that the tube is cooled and kept to a constant temperature and that the reaction is not controlled by kinetics, I think that at the end of the tube (if long enough) it can be considered in thermodynamic equilibrium.
2. If the tube is adiabatic then a distribution of temperature inside should arise. For each temperature there exists an equilibrium constant, and thus a different composition. In this case, would there be thermodynamic equilibrium at each single step (infinitesimal) along the tube? Again, this is considering an equilibrium-controlled reaction.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Is it are these descriptions correct?

Comment: Sure.  If the tube is long enough, the system will reach a final temperature and composition.  You can even precisely calculate it by considering the same reaction mixture in an adiabatic batch reactor, and waiting until the system has equilibrated.

Comment: @bon The actual question is related to the second point, if it is correct or not!

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes, but how about the second point, each step of the reaction can be considered as in equilibrium? If so it is correct, there exist an optimal temperature to maximize the calories conversion

Comment: What you describe is a 'flow reactor' commonly  used to measure rate constants in gas phase reactions by placing the detector at different places along the tube. Question (1) yes; eventually equilibrium is reached at some point at a point distant from the source inlet. (2) If the temperature is not controlled the rate constant will change as the gases travel along the tube and equilibrium reached sooner if the temperature is raised. No reliable rate constant can now be obtained.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks, I have a question more on this type of reactor. Back to your answer, what do you mean by no reliable rate constant can be obtained? The other doubt is related to Le Chatelier's Principle application, in a closed volume at equilibrium, removing the products increases the reactants conversion (to counteract the change, reaction shifted to the right); in a flow system how this principle apply, since reactants and products continuously move? Is the reaction always shifted to products?

Comment: You can't get more than 100% conversion, and that would correspond to some specific final temperature.  You can then evaluate the equilibrium constant at that hypothetical limiting temperature, and use it to determine what the conversion actually would be if that temperature prevailed.  It will certainly be less than 100%.  So the actual final temperature will be less than for 100% conversion.  With regard to @porphyrin 's comment on a flow reactor, this type of reactor is widely used in industry to carry out chemical reactions in continuous processes.

Comment: What I meant wrt rate constants was that you start at zero conversion at the input point and distance of detector along tube corresponds to time at constant flow. Thus, if the temp changes along the tube, the rate constant changes (Arrhenius ) also so a different amount of  reaction has occurred at a given distance than expected and so rate constant computed will be in error.